# Parse.com revoke API key

Tags: parse-platform, api-key

Is it possible to revoke an API key for an application? I don't want to create a new app, but if my key is compromised, I want to use another key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the only way to reset the master key is by contacting Parse for a new one.

Report the incident as a bug report [here](https://parse.com/help#report).

[Source](https://www.parse.com/questions/i-believe-my-master-key-was-compromised-and-needs-to-be-reset)